# Field Calculator Mass Change Freezing issue, Any other options?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

I have a list of ~2300 points, that i need to change a whole field's ("JointUse") attributes from null to "N" (for No). I've tried doing the basic field calculator change but I'm assuming since I'm running through Citrix its a bit much for it to handle (which seems pathetic). I'm not too familiar with scripts and was wondering if there was a way that would avoid this freezing issue.

EDIT: 
The data is a feature class
Subsetting was my initial attempt to fix but it will still give me issues at as low as 30 points. Sometimes it works, sometimes it freezes.

I will try some of your other suggestions and post back Branco
Data is taken from an oracle database. I am not used to this style setup so these performance errors and issues are new to me.

Answer (score 2):

**Things you may be able to try:**

-Get a better internet connection to your VPN.

-Try running subsets of your records (500/time)
--Select 500 records (so they're blue), run the Field Calculator, rinse/repeat

-Try **not** doing it during an edit session (faster but can't revert)

-Make sure the VPN is letting you access your license server (if applicable)
--You probably can't access ArcMap (if you need to connect to your license server) if not, but just in case it is something to verify

-Try using arcpy via the interactive window and an [UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/UpdateCursor/018v00000064000000/)

```
with arcpy.UpdateCursor('LAYERNAME') as rows:
  for row in rows:
    row.JointUse = 'N'
    rows.updateRow(row)
```

-Contact your IT department/issue a help ticket and ask them for their opinion on your current configuration.

Post updates by **editing** your question, and you may get better/more ideas.  Also, what **format** is your data in?  I based my answer off the idea of working with a shapefile/feature class or local layer and not a server layer.